# What is the easiest way to make a bootable Ghost disk?

Tags: windows, bootable-media, norton-ghost

I need to make a bootable [Norton Ghost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_%28software%29) disk (CD/DVD - this old PC won't boot from USB keys! And that is what I usually use.). What would be the quickest/easiest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) is a pretty good tool because it's a live Windows CD that you make from your own Windows installation, and it can be loaded up with a pretty good select of [plugins](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/plugins/) such as Symantec's Ghost program might be a good choice for. You do have to build it though, it's not a pre-built item.

Good luck on your search.

With **[WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/)** you can easily deploy your BartPE CD onto a bootable USB stick.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Ghost, you could use a [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) alternative such as [Clonezilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clonezilla), [g4l](http://sourceforge.net/projects/g4l/), a freeware backup application like the free version of [Macrium Reflect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macrium_Reflect), or something like [Acronis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronis#Products) - which while payware, is really easy, and comes with a bootable backup/restore disk. There's a huge load of applications that'll do what you want, [if you're willing to loo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_cloning_software)k.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest and easiest way would be to download an [ISO image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) from the Internet and burn it to a CD. There are many good ISO images to choose from that have Ghost. There are tools collections such as [BartPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BartPE) (mentioned in another answer).

In order to make a Ghost boot disk, I think it is the legitimate way. You have to install the Windows version of Ghost and in the program there is an option to create boot disks.